# Low resolution of Developer icon on Google Play

Tags: android, icons, google-play-services

In Google Play Console, after clicking the **Developer page** at the left panel, I uploaded a **Developer icon**. However, the **resolution** of the image presented on Google Play is quite **low**. (the orange arrow in the image below)

On the other hand, the **Header image**, the setting of which is just below the Developer icon, is presented with acceptable resolution on Google Play. (the green background banner in the image below)

[image]

How to improve the resolution of the Developer icon on Google Play?

**Update**:

Seems like it's a bug of Google Play app. The resolution of the Developer icon is ok when Google Play app is set to be in **dark mode**. (the orange arrow in the image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behaviour of the Play Store, there is no workaround. The icon is really small so you don't have to worry about this. The visual issues will be negligible when viewed from an actual device.

*Looks almost like this from an actual device :*

[image: What it looks like when zoomed out.]

Comment: Seems like it's a bug of Google Play app. The resolution of the Developer icon is ok when Google Play app is set to be in dark mode. The question has been updated.

Comment: But they're similar in dark/white mode on my devices, I'm using PixelExperiencePlus-11.0. This can be a rom specific bug too.

Comment: @explotr Thank you for sharing this observation  :)